# Image + float array as input in a Keras model

Tags: python, keras, input, concatenation

I have an image as input on my model, but I need to input some floats as well as support information about the image, but I don´t want it to go through all the convolutions, I want it to go directly to my dense layers as information on how to train it. I know about the concatenate layer but I don´t know how to use it in the input, or if that is how it should be done.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have a `backbone` which can be any convolutional neural nets (VGG, ResNet, etc.). Before the dense layer, you usually have a `Flatten()` one (or, in modern neural nets, you usually have a pooling layer like `GAP` or `GeM`) which prepares a 1D vector as input to your Dense layer. That's where you can concatenate with your floats.

Code example using Functional API:

```python
class MyModel(tf.keras.Model):
  def __init__(self, num_output_classes):
    super().__init__()
    self.backbone = tf.keras.applications.ResNet50(
        input_shape=(224, 224, 3), include_top=False)
    self.pool = tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()
    self.concat = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate(axis=-1)
    self.dense = tf.keras.layers.Dense(num_output_classes)

  def call(self, inputs):
    # Unpack the inputs. `additional_floats` should be 1D
    image, additional_floats = inputs

    # Run image through backbone and get a feature vector
    x = self.backbone(image)
    x = self.pool(x)

    # Concatenate with your additional floats
    x = self.concat([x, additional_inputs])

    # Classification, or whatever you might need on top
    return self.dense(x, activation='softmax')
```

Comment: cool, but how would I call fit, or train_on_batch with those inputs?

Comment: I tried to build it with this as input_shape: [(None, 256, 256, 3), (None, 2048)] and got this error: You cannot build your model by calling `build` if your layers do not support float type inputs. Instead, in order to instantiate and build your model, `call` your model on real tensor data (of the correct dtype).